# How to handle a Firebase Auth unhandled exception in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

When a user for my app tries to sign up with Facebook when they've already signed up with google, Flutter gives this error from the console. How would I handle this error in my code? I presume the `exception` part of the output is the error code?

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address., null)
E/flutter ( 5581): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
```

Here is my code:

```
void loginWithFb() async {
    var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
    print('Signing up with fb...');
    setState(() {
      _showProgressIndicator = true;
    });

    FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithFBAcc();
    uId = user?.uid;


    if(uId != null) {
      print('Signed in: $uId');
      widget.onSignedIn(user);
    } else {

      print('fb login cancelled');

    }

//    _showAlert(context);
    setState(() {
      _showProgressIndicator = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: use `.catchError((e){print(e);})`

Comment: thanks can I use that with an async function?

Comment: yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return user.uid;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e.code;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Posting code is great, but it would be nice if you could add an explanation to your answer which would help further viewers understand what's going on.